# for(SKNode * node in nodes) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sknode

Am new to swift and learning
I use 
" for(SKNode * node in nodes) "
for selecting the particular node with its name in objective-C but in swift I need some help to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just read the documentation: [For Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(touchLocation) as [SKNode]

            for node in nodes {
                if let nodeName = node.name {
                    if nodeName == "myNodeName" {
                        println("node tapped")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

To check if a node is tapped, iterate with for loop. Loop through the SKNodes, and check if the node name matches. Difference is that instead of (SkNode* node) we have :

```
let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(touchLocation) as [SKNode]
```

Answer (score 0):

in SWIFT

```
for node in nodes {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using "for" loop in swift :

```
    let arrStrings = ["one","two","three","four"]

    for str in arrStrings
    {
       if str=="two"
       {
         println("\(str)")
       }
    }
```